# jquery use :contains to edit css for other divs

Tags: jquery, contains

I am trying to use :contains to change the css styles of a div if another div contains certain words, for example I can use this code to find change the parent, but how can I do it for a div that isnt a parent?

```
$(".readmorecircle:contains('Huge')").parent().css("border", "2px solid #ffff00");
```

I have a fiddle set up, and its the last line that I cant figure out??

http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/nTJTg/4/

it would also be good to know how to change the css of several divs at the same time based on the contents of a div.

Comment: So what are you trying to do with the last line? Change the parent div of the `p` containing "Huge"?

Comment: no,  but i'm trying to change the border of #readmorecircle3, which isnt the parent, I will need to re use the code to change several divs all over the page

Comment: In the above code, instead of ".parent()" I want to use a seperate #div, what do I cahnge this to to target  #readmorecircle3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your last line in the fiddle, is not correct. In place of this:

```
$(".readmorecircle:contains('Huge')").readmorecircle3().css("border", "2px solid #ffff00");
```

It should be this:

```
$(".readmorecircle:contains('Huge')").parent().css("border", "2px solid #ffff00");
```

Also, the HTML for the last is not correct. In place of this:

```
<div id="readmorecircle3"></div>
    <p class="readmorecircle">Huge</p>
```

It should be this:

```
<div id="readmorecircle3">
   <p class="readmorecircle">Huge</p>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

```
if ($(".readmorecircle:contains('Huge')").length) {
    $("#readmorecircle3").css("border", "2px solid #ffff00");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm trying to change the border of #readmorecircle3, which isnt the parent, I will need to re use the code to change several divs all over the page

Comment: I dont want it to be a parent